Geo Nodes: Set object scale between spline points
Coming from 3ds max and Raiclone to create parametric models like houses I wonder how to change the scale of an object between 2 spline points on a multiple points spline:
I can get that to work between a simple curve using only 2 points already. I'd like to know if there is a way to get the information of distance/length between spline points to scale my instance mesh on a particular axis. Actually it's taking the whole spline length into account.
Also, would there be a way to select an instanced mesh from a collection from its length?
What I mean: Longer length between 2 points on a spline = select longer instanced mesh from the collection.
shorter length between 2 points on a spline = select shorter instanced mesh from the collection.
I hope everything is clear enough.




Hello and welcome 1k0, you can post your .blend here: https://blend-exchange.com/ So we don't have to rebuild your setup...

I would recommend to post this as a separate question : "Also, would there be a way to select an instanced mesh from a collection from its length?".

Thanks you two!

Hi, 1k0.. welcome to BSE. As Stef  suggests.. this does look like 2 questions? .You're welcome to ask them both.. in Stack Exchange's  format, that's the way to go, for clarity, and the searchable archive.

Here you are:

Basically i just take the 2 positions (index + 1, index) and store the midpoint (mix vector), the direction (vector subtract) and the distance to my "points" branch. Then i reposition the points on the midpoint (set position), rotate the instance along the direction (align euler to vector) and scale them by the distance (scale instances).

i instanced the icosphere just for demo purposes, so you know, where the point of the curves are.

Thanks a lot Chris! It's working great now :D

you are welcome
